# Looping over a huge list, check string equal to true

Tags: java, performance, list, search, collections

I have a requirement as below:

```
List<User> userList = listOfUsers(); // Morethan 50,000 users
```

I need to find a user status from the list of users. if any one of the users is active then break the loop.

what is the efficient way to handle this in java ?

Comment: a database, or cached lookups via a map (or similar)

Comment: I'll advise using an hashmap for this. Maybe convert the list to an hashmap and go from there.

Comment: how many times do you need to find an active user on the same list? if only once, then the fastest way is to iterate: O(n). If multiple times, then you may start to see savings from O(n) initialization and O(1) lookups via hashmaps

Comment: Why are you loading a huge amount of data into the memory?
Are you using any kind of database as a data store?

Comment: @chuckskull Using a DB may or may not be right: 1. 50k is a lot for a mobile, but OK for a laptop. 2. Indexing on a `boolean isActive` is pretty inefficient, so the DB will perform a full scan anyway, i.e., exactly the operation the OP wants to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to accelerate the search (*Without Using Java 8*) is by searching both directions in the `ArrayList` (i.e from the beginning to the middle, and from the end to the middle) at the same time via using ***multi-threading***, I created this example and tested it against ***1 million*** object/user to check if any of them is active (*Note that I made only **one** user active and put him in the **middle** to see the **longest** time the search may take*).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class User {
    // some fields to test
    String name;
    boolean active;
    //volatile means all writes up to the volatile variable 
    //from other any thread are now visible to all other threads.
    //so they can share working on that variable
    static volatile boolean finishFirst = false; // to announce first thread finish
    static volatile boolean finishSecond = false; // to announce second thread finish
    static volatile boolean found = false; // // to announce if an active user found

    /**
     * Simple Constructor
     * @param name
     * @param active
     */
    public User(String name, boolean active){
        this.name = name;
        this.active = active;
    }


   public static void main(String[] args) {

     // create an ArrayList of type User
     ArrayList<User> list = new ArrayList<User>();

     // populate it with 1 MILLION user!!
     int i=0;
     for(;i<1000000; i++){
         // make only the one in the very middle active to prolong the search to max
         if(i==500000){
             list.add(new User(String.valueOf(i),true));
         }
         else{
             list.add(new User(String.valueOf(i),false));
         }

     }
     System.out.println("End of Adding " + i + " User" );

     // to measure how long it will take
     long startTime, endTime;
     startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

     System.out.println("Found Any Active: "+ isAnyActive(list)); // invoke the method

     endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
     System.out.println(endTime-startTime + " MilliScond");




   }

   public static boolean isAnyActive(ArrayList<User> list){
       found = false;

       // create two threads, each search the half of the array
       // so that shall save time to half
       Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
         @Override
         public void run() {
            // read one more index in case the size is not an even number
             // so it will exceed the middle in one -> no problem at all
             for(int i=0; i<=(list.size()/2)+1; i++){ 
                   if(list.get(i).active) {
                       found = true;
                       finishFirst = true;
                       break; 
                   }
             } 
             finishFirst = true; // in case did not find any 
         }  
       });

       // second thread the same, but read from the end to the middle 
       Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable(){
             public void run() {
                 for(int i=list.size()-1; i>=list.size()/2; i--){
                       if(list.get(i).active) {
                           found = true;
                           finishSecond = true;
                           break; 
                    }
                 }
                 finishSecond = true;
            }      
       });

       // start both thread
       t2.start();
       t1.start();

       // while one of them has not finished yet
       while(!finishFirst || !finishSecond){
        // but in case not finished looping but found an active user
           // break the loop
               if(found){break;} 
        }

       return found; // return the result
   } 
}
```

**Test**

```
End of Adding 1000000 User
Found Any Active: true
31 MilliScond
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8 solution with method reference:

`userList.stream().filter(User::isActive).findFirst()`

It'll return `Optional` so you could map over it.

Comment: Thanks. I will consider this if i use 8. but i am using java 7

Comment: @WhoAmI other option would be the answer suggested by Ramon. However, I'd suggest to find a different approach then loading > 50k users into app memory.

Answer (score 1):

The efficient way is to do that filter with SQL if you are using that. Select just the active users....

When you have all that list to work with java it will be slow as hell and there is no magic here, you will need to iterate.

```
public User getActiveUserFromList(userList) {
  for (User user : userList) {
    if (user.isActive()) {
      return user;
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

If you have that list anyway ordered you can try to hack it, let's assume it is ordered by active status

```
public Boolean isAnyActive(userList) {
   if (userList.first().isActive()) { // try first
     return true;
   }
   if (userList.last().isActive()) {  // if its ordered and there is an active user, the last surely will be active, since first wasn't
     return true;
   }
   return false;
}
```

Comment: thanks. Yes I am trying this way only but it takes time to iterate. Is there any other way?

Comment: Java 8 Lambda has stream().findFirst() which will return the first active user.

Comment: Thanks @RamondePaulaMarques. I dont want to continue the loop if any one of the user status is active.

Answer (score 0):

I would certainly think about using Java 8 Lambda.  I have written an example class:

```
package com.chocksaway;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
* Author milesd on 05/06/2017.
*/

class Name {
    private String name;
    private Boolean status;

    public Name(String name, Boolean status) {
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Boolean getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
}

public class FindFirstInStream {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Name> userList = new ArrayList<>();

        userList.add(new Name("James", false));
        userList.add(new Name("Eric", true));
        userList.add(new Name("David", false));

        Name firstActiveName = userList.stream()
            .filter(e -> e.getStatus().equals(true))
            .findFirst()
            .get();

        System.out.println(firstActiveName.getName());
    }
}
```

---

**I've created a Name class**, with name, and status.

I populate a userList with James, Eric, and David.

**I use Java 8 stream to filter**, and return the first "*active*" name (Eric).

This is stored in "firstActiveName".

Answer (score 0):

You may use Collections ArrayDeque. ArrayDeques will use half of the iteration  to find the active user. In your case

```
ArrayDeque sample = new ArrayDeque(userList);

    for(int i=0;i<sample.size();i++){
                if(sample.pollFirst().status.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    break;
                }

                if(sample.pollLast().status.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                    break;
                }
                if(sample.size()==0) break;

            }
```

Comment: Thanks Let me try

Comment: Interesting Suggestion, But you need to be careful because this checks one item at a time (not parallel searching) but indeed checks from the beginning and from the end. But again one at a time. Added to that They are not thread-safe and Null elements are prohibited in the array deques. Furthermore, They do not support concurrent access by multiple threads.

Answer (score 0):

Because I see many Java 8 streaming solutions that do not use parallel streams, I add this answer. You have a large collection on which you do the matching, so you can use the power of parallelStreams when you would opt to use Java 8.

```
Optional<User> result = userList.parallelStream().filter(User::isActive).findAny();
```

Using a parallelStream will split the stream into multiple sub-streams which is more performant for very large collections. It uses the ForkJoinPool internally to process these sub-streams. The only difference here is that I use `findAny()` instead of `findFirst()` in this solution.

This is what Javadoc has to say about `findAny()`:

> The behavior of this operation is explicitly nondeterministic; it is
>   free to select any element in the stream. This is to allow for **maximal
>   performance in parallel operations**; the cost is that multiple
>   invocations on the same source may not return the same result. (If a
>   stable result is desired, use findFirst() instead.)

Here is a nice [tutorial on Parallelism](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/parallelism.html) from Oracle.